# multiple negative lag (aka lead) variable in h2o

Tags: lag, h2o

**Background:**
Given that

- I have a large table (~20 million rows, 40 columns).
- I am using h2o to fit some models on the data in the table.
- I found there is "h2o.difflag1" that gives a lag-1 transform.
- I want to create a column that is "lead ~8000".

**Question**
How do I make a 3600 lead without making 8000 lags on 39 columns using h2o on my 20-million row dataset?  Is there a better way to do this?